Sigmoid vs heaviside step function
I am curious about a relationship between the elementwise sigmoid function $\sigma$ and unit heaviside step function $H$. I know that as the slope of $\sigma$ increases, it gets closer to $H$. However, for my problem, I have a a state vector $v(i) \in \mathbb R^n$ whose $j^{\text{th}}$ entry $v_j(i) \in [0,1]$ at $i^{\text{th}}$ iteration. The state vector can be computed as $v(i+1) = H(Av(i))$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$. I am replacing $H$ with $\sigma$ to make each $v_j(i+1)$ a continuous function. Is there any way to show that $\sigma(v_j(i)) \geq 0.5$ implies $H(v_j(i))=1$? Any related works? Thank you!

I think it is a good idea to work with a sigmoidal function, such as $tanh(x)$, instead of the Heaviside function $H(x)$. I don't think there is a rule how to transform the sigmoidal to the Heavyside function. So you are free to invent your own rule !

Technically the sigmoid crosses the 0.5 threshold exactly at $x=0$ so the implication is trivial, but as one commenter wrote the choice of transformation is yours as a designer and not dictated by mathematical rules. In fact both the slope and the horizontal shift of the sigmoid are model parameters that you can vary on a test dataset to study their effect on the performance of the model.

$σ(0)=.5$ and $σ'(x)>0$ for any real $x$, so any $σ(x)>.5$ implies that $x>0$, so if $x>0$ then $H(x)=1$.  Note that if $x=0$ then $H(x)=σ(x)=.5$
